# Url rewrite in ASP.NET MVC or web.config

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting

Ignore the base problem. My custom built javascript library is moronic when it comes to looking up resources. Ok, it's me, but I don't care. At this point I'm looking for an ugly work around.

The client requests

```
http://localhost/Activities/Index/dojo/resources/blank.gif
```

and I want to say, your're a moron behind my teeth, but front with a smile and serve the image which of course is located at

```
http://localhost/dist/dojo/resources/blank.gif
```

No redirect. I guess it's what's called a rewrite. Solve that for me, please. Either in the route table or web.config, whichever performs the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be easily achieved with the [IIS 7.0 rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite):

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="resources">
      <match url="Activities/Index/(.*)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="dist/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Great thanks. That's a regexp right? So Activities/Index/(.*(\.gif|\.png|\.js|\.css)) will work?